# Hardware Fragment Sorting?

Tags: opengl, transparency

I'm writing a rendering engine in OpenGL.

I Want to do order independent transparency.

I had heard somewhere that some GPUs have support for actually sorting the fragments of all the objects in the scene based on depth and then drawing them.

I then realized that this feature is likely very important to many people.

Does OpenGL have a built-in fragment sorting algorithm, or access to this hardware?

Comment: To my knowledge, the only hardware which had built-in automatic support for order-independent transparency was the GPU of the Sega Dreamcast.

Comment: My understanding is that algorithms like this are implemented with more generic hardware features like unordered access views / image load/store, rather than a dedicated hardware pipe just for order independent blending.